# Prevent recursive extraction with the `extract` package

Tags: include, extract

I am trying out the `extract` package to save parts of my document that I later want to repeat as a summary at the end.

I am hitting a recursion problem: If I include the output of the extraction in the same document, then the echoed content will be extracted again, leading to infinite recursion. If I copy the previous extract file first and only include the copy, then I still end up with a larger and larger extract file every time I run latex.

So what I would really need is a way to tell disable `extract` once the main body of the document is over. The `extractskip` environment doesn't seem to help, because it's still parsed during each run:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatimcopy}
%% "touch foo.ext" before first use
\VerbatimCopy{foo.ext}{foo-final.ext}
\usepackage[active,generate=foo.ext,header=false,handles=false,copydocumentclass=false,extract-env=foo]{extract}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}abc\end{foo}
\begin{foo}def\end{foo}
\begin{foo}xyz\end{foo}

\section*{Summary of Foo}

\input{foo-final.ext}  %% boom

\end{document}
```

I'm currently using `\IfFileExists` to only enable the extraction during the first run, but that's brittle because you need to manually delete the extract file if any of the extracted content changes. Is there a way to automatically stop the extraction within one run?

Comment: I believe you should use something like `generate=foo.ext`; choose whatever strange extension you can think to, but not `.aux` that's used by LaTeX. Please, make a complete example.

Comment: @egreg: I don't think that's related. (The default is actually `.tex`.) The problem is that while the `\input` is being processed, the environments contained therein are extracted again.

Comment: Maybe (but I don't think so). However, how do you think people can test your case? You even have syntax errors in the code you present. And no `foo` environment.

Comment: @egreg: Good point. I added an example with copying. You need to `touch foo.ext` the first time round. If you keep running it, the summary gets bigger and bigger. Strangely, if you output `foo.ext` directly, the file is just empty (so there's no immediate recursion). This was different in my real document, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: From the documentation: “When the [`handles`] option is set to false, the generated file can be `\inputed` or `\included` by *another* file immediately after production.” (I just added emphasis on “another”).

Comment: @KerrekSB: How about trying this: [Write to file](http://pastebin.com/bmT52Ee7)

Comment: @Werner: I thought I had tried that, but it suffered from the problem of [exceeding capacity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318778/accumulate-contents-of-an-environment). Coming to think of it, though, maybe that was because I had recursively defined environments. Let me check that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a bit of a sabotage approach: before your summary, replace the command that `extract` uses to write to the file with an empty command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimcopy}
\VerbatimCopy{foo.aux}{foo-final.aux}
\usepackage[active,generate=foo.aux,extract-env=equation,header=false,handles=false,copydocumentclass=false]{extract}

\begin{document}
The following text should be extracted:
\begin{equation}
x+3=y
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x+4=z
\end{equation}

\newcommand{\exignore}[1]{}
\makeatletter
\def\XTR@writeout{\exignore}   % cf. extract.sty v1.8 line 82
\makeatother
\section{Summary of Foo}
\input{foo-final.aux}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: If it works, I have no problem with sabotage! :-)