# Accumulate text inside verbatim blocks

Tags: verbatim, external-files

Is there a way to accumulate all the text inside `verbatim` blocks to an external file?

I know of the package `extract`, but it seems to be accumulating the environment `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` statements as well as the content, which I want to avoid.

I also tried following this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318778/accumulate-contents-of-an-environment), and wrote this code

```
\def\mycode{}

\let\oldverbatim\verbatim
\let\oldendverbatim\endverbatim

\RenewEnviron{verbatim}{%
\def\xBODY{\expandonce\BODY}%
\xappto\mycode{\xBODY^^J}
\oldverbatim
\BODY
\oldendverbatim}
```

but it's giving me too many `Undefined control sequence` errors that I don't quite understand.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your code is supposed to show... do you want to write stuff to a file **and** show the contents in your document?

Comment: Yes, the new `verbatim` environment should show the code like the original one, but also somehow produce an external file that accumulates all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the `filecontentsdef` package.

We define a new environment `collectverb` which first reads the environment body into a macro `\collectverb@tl` using `\filecontentsdefmacro`. The contents is then written to the output file `\collectverb@out` and after that printed in the document. For the typesetting of the code internal macros of the standard `verbatim` environment are used, so the result should look identical to your current output.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}

\makeatletter

\newwrite\collectverb@out
\immediate\openout\collectverb@out=\jobname-verb.tex

\newenvironment{collectverb}{%
    \begingroup
    \filecontentsdefmacro\collectverb@tl
}{%
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro
    \endgroup
    \immediate\write\collectverb@out{\collectverb@tl}%
%
    \let\@xverbatim=\relax
    \@verbatim
    \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`\ %
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\ }%
    \collectverb@tl
    \endverbatim
}

\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\collectverb@out}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text ...
\begin{collectverb}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\end{collectverb}
... more text ...
\begin{collectverb}
\begin{document}
  \textcolor{blue}{Hello world!}
\end{document
\end{collectverb}
... and even more text.
\end{document}
```

creates a file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \textcolor{blue}{Hello world!}
\end{document
```

and prints

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the `scontents` package you can do this in a very simple way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[store-env=collectverb]{scontents}
\begin{document}
Some text ...
\begin{scontents}[write-env=file.txt]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\end{scontents}
\typestored[1]{collectverb}
... more text ...
\begin{scontents}[write-env=file2.txt]
\begin{document}
  \textcolor{blue}{Hello world!}
\end{document}
\end{scontents}
\typestored[2]{collectverb}
... and even more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]